# Old USB driver on 12.10

Tags: drivers

I have a USB device that comes with a generic Linux driver in the form of a kernel module. It's a .ko file that I'm supposed to install. However, it was compiled for version 2.16.18-53 of the Linux kernel. I don't have access to the source.

Is it possible to get this working on Ubuntu 12.10 with Linux 3.2.0-39-generic-pae?

Answer (score 1):

- The module will refuse to load by default.
- You can try to force it with `modprobe -f`. Maybe you are lucky.
- Best method is to recompile it against the new kernel. Look into [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS), that's what is used in Ubuntu for packages that use kernel modules. Here is an [example with a mouse module](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1589390&highlight=dkms%20mouse).
- Another possible method might be to post the file on a (relevant) mailing list and ask if someone could/can recompile it.

But ... having a source file might be crucial.